# How to delete duplicate record in mysql rapidly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has about 100000 rows and I want to delete duplicate record 
To do this I am using `JOIN` query

```
DELETE c1 FROM contacts c1
INNER JOIN contacts c2 
WHERE
    c1.id > c2.id AND 
    c1.email = c2.email;
```

But on executing above query the system get stuck  because of `Cross JOIN`
What should I do?

Comment: I am not very familiar with MySQL but can't you use a sub-select? Select all duplicated records and do a "where c1.id in"? Some small example population would be nice to get a more visual idea of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an `INNER` join as a `CROSS` join.
Your code should be:

```
DELETE c1 
FROM contacts c1 INNER JOIN contacts c2 
ON c1.id > c2.id AND c1.email = c2.email;
```

You can also try to get the minimum id for each email and join to the table:

```
DELETE FROM contacts
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT t.id FROM (
    SELECT MIN(id) id FROM contacts
    GROUP BY email
  ) t
);
```

Also create an index on the column `email` if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an aggregation to get the minimum `id` and deleting all but that.  Assuming `id` is unique:

```
delete c
    from contacts c left join
         (select c2.email, min(c2.id) as min_id
          from contacts c2
          group by c2.email
         ) c2
         on c2.min_id = c.id
    where c2.id is null;
```

This deletes all ids in the `contacts` that are not the minimum `id` for their email.  It is also compatible with MySQL limitations on the `delete` statement.